# wc -l filename is showing one row less. Please guide

Tags: files, wc

with command
wc -l filename
it is showing one row less when total number of rows inside file are 2 but it is showing 1 only. Please guide.

Comment: Of course you are aware that *wc -l* "print the **newline counts**". That is of course… strictly not necessarily related to the number of **rows**

Answer (score 2):

`wc -l` counts the number of newline characters, which is the number of properly delimited lines.

What's likely happening in your case is that your file has some bytes after the last newline character.

That file is not a valid text file as a result, you'll find that some applications ignore those extra bytes and some treat it as an extra line (some add the missing newline).

As per the POSIX definition of text, those extra bytes don't constitute a line.

POSIX compliants `awk` however are required to consider those as forming an extra record, so:

```
awk 'END {print NR}' < your-file
```

Would count it.

Assuming that's the case, best would be to add that missing newline character with:

```
printf '\n' >> your-file
```

Example:

```
$ printf 'a\nb' | wc -l
1
$ printf 'a\nb\n' | wc -l
2
$ printf 'a\nb' | awk 'END {print NR}'
2
```